# How to set and map environment data in loopback js?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have followed loopback documentation to setup deployment & environment specific configuration.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Environment-specific-configuration.html

There is a place where i need to get data source connector, for that i have configured and accessing data source throughout in the application. and it is working fine.

`module.exports.DataSources = app.dataSources.hmsDs.connector;`

But after configure for deploying application in production as documentation says. I am getting error.

```
module.exports.DataSources = app.dataSources.applianceDs.connector;
                                                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connector' of undefined
```

### datasource.production.js

```
module.exports = {
    applianceDs: {
        hostname: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT || 27017,
        database: 'applianceDB',
        user: process.env.DB_USER || "",
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || "",
        name: "applianceDs",
        connector: 'mongodb',
    }
}
```

and when i tried to access data source as follow,

```
var { applianceDs }= require('../datasource.production');
module.exports.DataSources = applianceDs.connector;
```

then getting error like this.

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: User is referencing a dataSource that does not exist: "applianceDs"
```

### Steps that i have followed at terminal

> $ export PRODUCTION=true
>
> $ export DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
>
> $ export DB_USER="me"
>
> $ export DB_PASSWORD="0000"
>
> $ nodemon app.js

Which step I am missing ? Is there something hidden in loopback js?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some advice which can help:

1. Configure NODE_ENV="production" env variable. I'm not sure, but loopback takes this value as the config postfix.
2. Try to pass env variables to run operation directly as it can be not inherited from the console (to check this point print process.env[$VARIABLE_NAME])

To pass env variables to operation:

```
PRODUCTION=true DB_HOST="127.0.0.1" DB_USER="me" DB_PASSWORD="0000" nodemon app.js
```